# Sqlite3 ConnectionString not found

Tags: java, database, sqlite

I am learning how to connect to a database for my future classes in University. I started today but I keep on getting errors when I try to test the connection of my database.

My question is what parameter does the `DriverManager.getConnection` take specifically. I have tried multiple different paths but none of the connections work. For each path I specified, it contains the `jdbc.jar` file and it also contains the `sqldiff`, `sqlite3`, and the `sqlite3_analyzer` files. Please and thanks!

Below you will see my code.

```
import java.sql.DriverManager

import java.sql.SQLException

import java.sql.Connection

/**
 * Created by admin on 2/11/2018.
 */

    public class Main {
        public static void main(String[]args){

        try{

            // Set up a connection String
            Connection myconnection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlite:C:\\Users\\admin\\Desktop\\JAVA\\UDEMYJAVA\\TestDB2018");
            System.out.println("Connection Successful");
        }catch (SQLException e){
            System.out.println("Something went wrong. " + e.getMessage());
        }



    }
}
```

This is the Error Message

Something went wrong. The database has been closed

Process finished with exit code 0

Comment: any help would be greatly appreciated.